# windows thread to accept a connection on a socket

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winsock2

I am familiar with pthreads, but new to Windows threading.  in Linux, a new thread can be started as:

```
pthread_t tid;
int rc = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, Threadfn, &newsocket);
assert (rc == 0);
//<snip>//
```

and `Threadfn` can reconstruct Socket easily:

```
void *Threadfn(void *vargp){
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    int *Socket = (int *) vargp;
    print("Socket is %d\n", *Socket);
    // recv/read/send etc.. 
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

How do we do this in Windows threads?

I create the thread:

```
HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Somethready, &ClientSocket, 0, NULL);
```

But I seem to have trouble with `Somethready`:

```
DWORD WINAPI Somethready(void *vargp) {
    printf("Thread got evoked\n");
    SOCKET *clientSocket = (SOCKET *)vargp;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = *clientSocket;
    printf("In thread, ClientSocket: %d\n", ClientSocket);
    /*
    char RecvBuf[bufsize];
    memset(RecvBuf, 0, bufsize);
    int n = recv(ClientSocket, RecvBuf, bufsize,0);
    print("We got %d bytes, we got %s\n", n, RecvBuf);
    */
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot seem to get it correct:

```
ClientSocket: 184
Thread got evoked
In thread, ClientSocket: -1 // <<-- this
```

What am I doing wrong? IOW, how can I pass the ClientSocket to the windows thread the rightway?

Thanks!

**Edit 1**

Here's how `ClientSocket` takes shape:

```
while (1) {
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("ClientSocket: %d\n", ClientSocket);
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Somethready, &ClientSocket, 0, NULL);
}
```

**Edit 2**

Thank you for the replies. I am a little shaken as I've never encountered this in Linux before - somehow the variables don't disappear that fast, at least whenever I tried. However this percolated the very first time I tried Windows threads. This is an invaluable lesson.

***Question:*** I noticed that if I add a slight delay (as shown below) right after calling the thread, it seems to behave OK, and we don't have a heap alloc to clean up later which makes it more attractive. I am curious whether this would be acceptable, or is this a disaster in waiting. Thanks!

```
while (1) {
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("ClientSocket: %d\n", ClientSocket);
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Somethready, &ClientSocket, 0, NULL);
    Sleep(30); // < -- this 
}
```

Comment: Does the variable get destroyed or overwritten before the thread starts? How do you know?

Comment: Make sure in the function where you call `HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Somethready, &ClientSocket, 0, NULL);`, `ClientSocket` variable doesn't go out of scope or deleted if it is allocated on heap.

Comment: Btw it appears that the posted Linux code also has the same problem (i.e. assuming that `newsocket` is a stack variable, it's very likely that `newsocket` will have been popped off the heap before the newly-spawned thread has had time to read it).  In both cases, the fix is to make sure the object the pointer points to remains valid until after the spawned thread is done using it.

Comment: Sadly, VC++ doesn't support C11's `thread.h` offerings. Before going to the Dark Side and using winapi, you may wish to consider upping your game to C++ and using the *fantastic* offerings of `<thread>` Mere words do no justice in describing how absolutely overjoyed I was when MS finally supported that  and got out of the stone age.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, pls see Edit 1 above.  How can I ensure `ClientSocket ` stays a while before it goes off the heap, so the thread can get to it? thanks!

Comment: You should extract a [mcve] from your code. Then, clean up all those "edit" sections within your question and make it complete and self-contained. In any case, your problem is passing address of local variables around to other threads and not syncronizing their lifetime/access. That's wrong on any OS, BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem in both the posted Windows code and the posted Linux code is that the argument you are passing to your newly-spawned thread is a pointer to a local variable on the parent-thread's stack, and that local variable is likely to have been popped off of the stack (and therefore maybe overwritten by some other data) before the child thread gets a chance to start running and look at it.

Therefore, the solution to the problem is to make sure that the data is still valid when the child thread looks at it.  There are several ways you can do this:

1) The easy (and usually best) way:  Instead of allocating the socket on the stack (as a local variable), allocate it from the heap instead:

```
// main thread
while (1) {
    SOCKET * pClientSocket = (SOCKET *) (malloc(sizeof(SOCKET)));  // allocate a SOCKET on the heap
    if (pClientSocket == NULL) {printf("malloc() failed!?\n"); break;}

    *pClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (*pClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        free(pClientSocket);  // avoid memory leak!
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("ClientSocket: %d\n", *pClientSocket);
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Somethready, pClientSocket, 0, NULL);
    if (thread == NULL)
    {
       closesocket(*pClientSocket);  // avoid socket leak!
       free(pClientSocket);  // avoid memory leak!
       printf("CreateThread failed!?\n");
    }
}

// child thread
DWORD WINAPI Somethready(void *vargp) {
    printf("Thread got evoked\n");
    SOCKET *pClientSocket = (SOCKET *)vargp;
    SOCKET ClientSocket   = *pClientSocket;  // make a copy of the heap-allocated SOCKET object into a local variable
    free(pClientSocket);                     // then free the heap-allocated SOCKET to avoid a memory leak

    printf("In thread, ClientSocket: %d\n", ClientSocket);
    [...]

    closesocket(ClientSocket);  // don't forget to close the socket when we're done
    return 0;
}
```

That will work well, because the heap-allocated `SOCKET` object (pointed to by `pClientSocket`) is guaranteed not to be destroyed until someone calls `free()` on it, and this code leaves it up to the child thread to do that, after it has copied its contents out into the local variable `ClientSocket`.

The only potential gotcha is that it's easy to accidentally create a memory-leak if you forget to call `free()` on the heap-allocated socket (e.g. in an error-handling early-return case), so you need to be careful about that.

2) The cheap-hack way.  This involves some potentially unsafe/undefined-behavior-invoking casting, but it works in practice, so a lot of people do it.  In this approach we simply stuff the SOCKET's value into the void-pointer directly.  I don't recommend it, but for completeness:

```
// main thread
while (1) {
    SOCKET ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("ClientSocket: %d\n", *ClientSocket);
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Somethready, (void *) ClientSocket, 0, NULL);
    if (thread == NULL)
    {
       closesocket(ClientSocket);  // avoid socket leak
       printf("CreateThread failed!?\n");
    }
}

// child thread
DWORD WINAPI Somethready(void *vargp) {
    printf("Thread got evoked\n");
    SOCKET ClientSocket = (SOCKET)vargp;  

    printf("In thread, ClientSocket: %d\n", ClientSocket);
    [...]

    closesocket(ClientSocket);  // don't forget to close the socket itself when we're done
    return 0;
}
```

3) The I'm-too-clever-a-programmer-for-my-own-good way:  In this approach, after spawning the child thread, we use a condition variable to block the main thread's execution until the child thread has indicated that it has started running and is no longer using the pointer-to-the-main-thread's-stack-variable.  I'm going to write this one in pseudocode, since I'm not at a windows machine to test it, but this should give you the general idea:

```
// global variables (or if you don't like global variables, you 
// could put these into a struct, along with the SOCKET object, 
// and pass a pointer-to-the-struct to the child thread instead)
CONDITION_VARIABLE wait_for_child_thread;
CRITICAL_SECTION   critical_section;

InitializeCriticalSection(&critical_section);
InitializeConditionVariable(&wait_for_child_thread);

// main thread
while (1) {
    SOCKET ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("ClientSocket: %d\n", *ClientSocket);
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Somethready, &ClientSocket, 0, NULL);
    if (thread != NULL)
    {  
       // Gotta wait here until the child thread wakes us up,
       // otherwise we risk invalidating (&ClientSocket) before he has used it!
       EnterCriticalSection(&critical_section);
       SleepConditionVariableCS(&wait_for_child_thread, &critical_section, INFINITE);
       LeaveCriticalSection(&critical_section);
    }
    else
    {  
       printf("CreateThread failed!?\n");
    }
}

// child thread
DWORD WINAPI Somethready(void *vargp) {
    printf("Thread got evoked\n");
    SOCKET * pClientSocket = (SOCKET *)vargp;
    SOCKET ClientSocket    = *pClientSocket;  // copy from main-thread's stack to our own stack

    // Now that we've made the copy, tell the main thread he can continue execution
    WakeConditionVariable(&wait_for_child_thread);

    printf("In thread, ClientSocket: %d\n", ClientSocket);
    [...]

    closesocket(ClientSocket);  // don't forget to close the socket itself when we're done
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... and "yet another" strategy that very-often works well in practice is to use a *global* (or "static") variable – anything that *isn't* allocated on the stack, but will be a reliably-unchanging place that both threads can get to.  If you intend to launch "only one instance" of a child thread, as is often the case, this very-simple strategy works just fine. *(And it applies to all operating-system environments ...)*

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. Could you please comment about adding a delay as in Edit 2?

Comment: That approach is properly done in my third example, in which the main thread blocks on a condition variable until after the child thread has finished gathering the data from the main thread's stack, and then awoken by `WakeConditionVariable()`.

Adding a fixed delay (e.g. via `Sleep()`) is never the right way to fix a race condition, because (a) it slows down your program unnecessarily, and (b) you can never guarantee that your arbitrary delay-time is going to be long enough in all cases, as in a non-realtime OS there is always the chance that the other thread might not run for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

> [How can I ensure `ClientSocket` stays a while before it goes off the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9488865/struggling-learner)

The common pattern is:

```
while (1) {
  SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
  ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);

  ...

  printf("ClientSocket: %d\n", ClientSocket);
  {
    SOCKET * psd = malloc(sizeof *psd); /* allocate in the parent */
    *psd = ClientSocket;
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Somethready, psd, 0, NULL);
  }
```

And inside the thread do:

```
DWORD WINAPI Somethready(void *vargp) {
  printf("Thread got evoked\n");
  SOCKET *pClientSocket = (SOCKET *)vargp;
  SOCKET ClientSocket = *pClientSocket;
  printf("In thread, ClientSocket: %d\n", ClientSocket);

  ...

  free(pClientSocket);  /* deallocate in the child */

  return 0;
}
```

BTW, the trap into you stepped is not specific to windows's threads but exactly the same for POSIX threads.